# Smart switch installation makes light blink

Tags: smart-switch

[image]Installed a Lutron Caseta smart switch for my outside porch lights but the lights just started blinking with no control from the switch plate.  What is the problem and how do I fix it?
Thanks.[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your post to indicate the _exact_ model number of your switch. Also, tell us what kind of light bulb (incandescent, LED, CFL, other) you have installed in the porch lights. Some clear, focused pictures of the wiring job you did might be helpful, as well, as the more experienced electricians here might see something that you may have missed.

Comment: you're using ground as neutral, which is very bad.

Answer (score 4):

Smart switches (and timers and motion detectors, etc.) need to get power for themselves in addition to passing through power to the switched device. They can do that one of several ways:

- Battery - But that leads to forgetting to change the battery, followed by forgetting there even *is* a battery, followed by a call to customer service. So batteries are not preferred.
- Neutral - This is by far the best solution. But many older homes don't have neutral in the switch box.
- Ground - This is *almost* the same as neutral. But not allowed except under very specific circumstances and very low current.
- Leak through Switched Hot - This *used to be* the simple solution. The problem is that with LEDs **they use so little power that it is enough to make them glow (a little annoying) or blink (**super annoying**).

If you have neutral in the switch box then get a switch that *requires* neutral and you should be all set. If you don't have neutral in the switch box then it gets more complicated.

Looking specifically at Lutron Caseta, [this one](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Lutron-Caseta-Smart-Switch-for-All-Bulb-Types-or-Fans-5A-White-PD-5ANS-WH-R/305090201#product-overview) says "Neutral wire required" and [this one](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Lutron-Caseta-Wireless-Smart-Lighting-Dimmer-Switch-and-Remote-Kit-for-Wall-and-Ceiling-Lights-White-P-PKG1W-WH-R/206754146?ITC=AUC-82980-23-12140#product-overview) says "does not require a neutral wire". If you have neutral, get one that requires neutral. If you don't, or if you're not sure, come back with a picture showing all the wires in your switch box.

Comment: The Lutron I have does require a neutral wire which I have (a white wire correct?). I hooked it to this bundle of white wires because it is in a box with four light switches. Should I just hook it to the one white wire only for the specific switch I am installing? Thanks for your help.

Comment: All the neutrals stay together.  Model # of Litton? Picture of wires?

Comment: Edit and then click on the sun and mountain icon. You can upload pictures directly from your computer or paste url from a web site like imgur.

Comment: I can't find the icon you mentioned.  I have to leave for while but I'll send pictures asap. Thanks again.

Comment: pictures uploaded.

Comment: I don't see a model # but there really only seems to be one match on the Lutron site, and the installation looks relatively straightforward. Are you sure you've got hot vs. switched-hot correct? Irrelevant on the old switch, critical for the new switch.